# How to find all Cube game Object in the scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

I'm looking for a way to find all CubeGameObject in the scene. I'm trying to do this :

```
Cube[] ballsUp = FindObjectsOfType (typeof(Cube)) as Cube[];
```

But cube isn't a game object type apparently.

I think i need to use something related to PrimitiveType but can figure out what and how to use it...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Cube is of primitive type. And Primitive type objects are not possible to find using **FindObjectsOfType**.
There are many ways to solve the above problem. The easiest is by using tags.
When you instantiate your cube object you can use tag "Cube".

```
GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
    cube.tag = "Cube";
```

Then you can get all the cube objects in scene with cube tags using

```
GameObject[] arrayofcubes = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Cube");
```

This will give all the array of GameObject cubes in the scene.

**FindObjectsOfType** can be used to find gameobjects with attached classed and not primitive types.

Another way to proceed is finding all objects with MeshFilters and Searching for the Desired primitive name in the mesh filter arrays

```
string[] meshNames = new string[5] {"Cube", "Sphere", "Capsule", "Cylinder", "Plane"};
MeshFilter[] allMeshFilters = FindObjectsOfType(typeof(MeshFilter)) as MeshFilter[];
foreach(MeshFilter thisMeshFilter in allMeshFilters)
{       
    foreach(string primName in meshNames)
    {           
        if (primName == thisMeshFilter.sharedMesh.name)
        {
            Debug.Log("Found a primitive of type: " + primName);                
        }           
    }       
}
```

[Geeting all the Object by their primitive type (C#)](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a script. Let's say your GameObjects have a script `MyScript`, then you could `FindObjectsofType` GameObject and `GetComponent` Myscript.

Hope this helps. Although, I know it's not the answer you want, it's definitely an idea worth trying as a last resort :)

Comment: I already did this but it's kinda messy so i was looking for another solution :). Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. If you are using the cube primitive of unity the mesh should be called "Cube" and while running "Cube Instance".

```
       var gameOjects =  GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>();
        foreach (var gameOject in gameOjects)
        {
            var meshFilter = gameOject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
            if (meshFilter != null && meshFilter.mesh.name == "Cube Instance")
                Debug.Log(gameOject.name); 
        }
```

tough this isn't very elegant or robust.

A more appropriate way would be to tag all cubes and get them by "FindGameObjectsWithTag"

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately my cubes are already tagged with different tag but i think it's the best way to do this :s.

Answer (score 0):

Then recommended way from Unity of doing this is to create a tag and then use `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag` to find all of them. `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag` returns array of objects in this tag.

For example, create a tag called "cubeTags" then go to each cube and change the tag to cubeTags. When you want to find all the cubes, you can just do:

```
GameObject[] cubes = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("cubeTags");
Cube[] ballsUp = new Cube[cubes.Length];
for(int i=0; i<cubes.Length; i++){
ballsUp = cubes[i].GetComponent<Cube>();
}
```

Comment: Oops. some one said the tag thing while I was writing mine. Either way, the script is here for others who may need it in the future